# How to center only one of the children inside a parent?

Tags: html, css

I have two elements inside a `div`. How can I vertically center only `p` element?

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

<div class="card">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Always in center vertically</p>
</div>
```

[image: Edit intelligent-curran-b73ip]

Comment: If it has to "always" be on the center of the div, you can try setting it to `position:absolute;margin-top:25%;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flex: display;` and `justify-content: center;`. This will align the `p` tag to center.

Align `h1` with `position: absolute;` to required position.

You should add `position: relative;` to `.card` for the `h1` with style `position: absolute;` to stay inside `.card`

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: beige;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Sample App</h2>
<div class="card">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p>Always in center vertically</p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you add `padding` to the parent and `width: 100%` to `h1`. How can you make `h1` stay inside parent?

Comment: You should add `position: relative;` to `.card` for the `h1` with style `position: absolute;` to stay inside `.card`

Comment: Not working. Add a `background-color` to `h1`.

Comment: Add `left: 0;` to `h1`

Comment: Yet still `h1` doesn't respect `padding` from parent.

Comment: You cannot expect a `position: absolute;` element to follow `margin` and `padding` values from parent

Comment: You have to make p element `position: absolute;` for that. You can follow other persons answer. He has already implemented that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70119465/6099327

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to **vertically** center `<p>` you can do that by using **absolute** position. First set your `.card` to `position:relative;` so that `<p>` remains inside it, now give `.card p` `position:absolute;` and set `top:50%;` but this will only center it to its parent element, to make it perfectly center we need to set `transform:translateY(-50%);`

```css
  .card {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    position:relative;
  }
  .card p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0;
  }
```

If you want to make it **horizontally** center as well then all you need to do is add `left:50%;` & `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to `.card p` where you set both translate X and Y axis to -50%.

```css
.card p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    margin: 0;
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).